# Discount on the product?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array:

```
$products = array(
  array(
    'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
    'qty'     => 1,
    'price'   => 39.95,
    'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
  ),
  array(
    'id'      => 'sku_567ZYX',
    'qty'     => 1,
    'price'   => 9.95,
    'name'    => 'Coffee Mug'
  ),
  array(
    'id'      => 'sku_965QRS',
    'qty'     => 1,
    'price'   => 29.95,
    'name'    => 'Shot Glass'
  )
);
```

I know how to count total price of products, but what i need is discount, to look like this way

Any 2 products 10% discount

Any 3 products 20% discount

5 + products  30%discount

The problem I have is that i know how to count numbers of array members, and i have qty i know that too, but i know how to do that ony counting by qty or array members? 
Is theere some solution to apply this discounts on $products array and display total price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the total number of products, you want to iterate through the array and add the quantities to get the total

```
$totalProducts = 0;
foreach($products as $product){
   $totalProducts += $product['qty'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on aynber's answer, this is how you could get the final total cost depending upon the number of items added.

```
$totalProducts = 0;
foreach($products as $product){
   $totalProducts += $product['qty'];
   $totalCost += $product['price'];
}

echo $totalProducts . "<br>";
echo $totalCost . "<br>";


if ($totalProducts == 2) {
  $totalCost = $totalCost - ($totalCost*.1);

} else if ($totalProducts == 3) {
  $totalCost = $totalCost - ($totalCost*.2);

} else if ($totalProducts >= 5) {
  $totalCost = $totalCost - ($totalCost*.3);
}

echo $totalCost;
```

Keep in mind if you're going to have a bunch of rules, it might be slightly more efficient to create a switch statement. But with three, I'd stick to an else if.